# How to user Response.Write to redirect to a url?

Tags: vb.net, redirect, response, response.redirect, response.write

I want to use Response.Write() in VB.NET to redirect to relative Url. I am using the following code:

### EDIT:

```
Response.Write(("account/msgbox.aspx?action=account&status=" & Convert.ToInt16(eAccountStatus).ToString))

Response.Write(("~/account/msgbox.aspx?action=account&status=" & Convert.ToInt16(eAccountStatus).ToString))
```

and

```
Response.Write(("/account/msgbox.aspx?action=account&status=" & Convert.ToInt16(eAccountStatus).ToString))
```

return the same in my case.

My application error event handler reports that the url being formed is invalid.

Here is what i am getting:

```
http://localhost:14154/~/http:/localhost:14154/account/msgbox.aspx?action=account&status=6
```

instead of this

```
http:/localhost:14154/account/msgbox.aspx?action=account&status=6
```

Response.Clear() before Response.Write() does nothing.

**I cannot use/switch to Response.Redirect() now** before the whole project uses Response.Write() and choosing to use Response.Redirect() will render all code useless that is written after Response.Write calls.

I just need clear the base url that is being appended somehow. Please let me know how may i achieve this.

Thanks you.

**P.S:** This code was working fine previously. Some developer made a change and now the Response.Write() is NOT causing the redirects as described above.

### EDIT

Stack Trace:

> System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): The file '/~/account/msgbox.aspx' does not exist.
>      at System.Web.UI.Util.CheckVirtualFileExists(VirtualPath virtualPath)
>      at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
>      at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
>      at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean throwIfNotFound)
>      at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp)
>      at System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath)
>      at System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, String virtualPath, String path)
>      at System.Web.HttpApplication.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>      at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
>   ::1
>   Details:
>   http:// localhost:14154/~/account/msgbox.aspx?action=account&status=6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK i solved the problem using this. Although i still need to understand how this works. but anyways i am posting it for anyone that run into similar problem.

Here is my new code.

```
Response.Write(("../account/msgbox.aspx?action=account&status=" & Convert.ToInt16(eAccountStatus).ToString))
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the code that sets baseUrl is setting it twice.
If you can't find that, you could kludge this code onto it:

```
Response.Write((baseUrl.replace("http://localhost:14154/~/http:/localhost:14154/", _
    "http://localhost:14154/") & "account/msgbox.aspx?action=account&status=" & _ 
    Convert.ToInt16(eAccountStatus).ToString))
```

You are better-off fixing it at the origin (where baseUrl is being set).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I removed the baseurl Completely. The problem still persists. Please review my edits. Thank you.

Comment: btw this was my code:

Dim baseUrl As String = Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + 
Request.Url.Authority + Request.ApplicationPath.TrimEnd("/"c) + "/"
                            
                            Response.Write(("account/msgbox.aspx?action=account&status=" & Convert.ToInt16(eAccountStatus).ToString))